# Refer a spring bean from the inherited context in Java config

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I am using the Java spring configuration using annotations.

If I have a configuration class A which is like

```
@Configuration
public  class A{

  @Bean(name="hello")
  public hello(){
     return new Hello();
  }

  @Bean(name="greeting")
  public greeting(){
     return new Greeting(hello());
  }
```

So here the greeting bean gets hello as a dependency.

How would I do this if I were to declare the greeting bean in a different configuration class say B and them import the configuration from A

```
@Configuration
public  class A{

  @Bean(name="hello")
  public hello(){
     return new Hello();
  }
}

@Configuration
@Import(A.class)
public  class B{

  @Bean(name="greeting")
  public greeting(){
     // what do i write here ? 
     // so that it is equivalent to 
     // return new Greeting(hello());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should be all you need.
Notice that I have injected your Hello bean as a method parameter. Spring DI shall take care of the rest.

```
@Configuration
@Import(A.class)
public  class B{

  @Bean(name="greeting")
  public greeting(Hello hello){
     return new Greeting(hello);
   }
```

Comment: what if i need to do  `Greeting g = new Greeting(); g.setGreetMessage(hello());`

Comment: @Autowired shall work as well. As for your earlier comment, you would do: g.setGreetMessage(hello);

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Should be able to make use of @Autowired annotation in B.

```
@Configuration
@Import(A.class)
public  class B{

  @Autowired 
  Hello hello;

  @Bean(name="greeting")
  public greeting(){
     return new Greeting(hello);
  }
```